# How to avoid Android getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) hanging emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, freeze

Whenever I call this method in the Android emulator:

```
SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
```

The emulator hangs. When searching for this problem, I find a lot of references of this being fixed back in 2009, but I'm currently using the latest SDK/Tools available at the current time (Dec 2011). API level 8 / v2.2.

Must I really implement code for checking if I run in the emulator and avoid all sensor based code?

Comment: Can the person who down-voted care to explain?

Comment: This seems to only happen for me using API 8.  Other APIs that I have tested (10, 15, 16) worked just fine.  Obviously this is not an answer, just another tidbit of information.  I'd LOVE an answer!  Anyone, anyone? Bueller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I experienced something similar with API7 in the emulator: the mentioned code causes the emulator to quit the program immediatly without any warning or log message. (API4 & API10 are ok; I did not test API8 specifically).

I have solved it by setting accelerometer to false in the AVD settings. (I tried this because of issues with the accelerometer in API14/API15 with launch from snapshot.)

Regards,

Arjan

Comment: I needed to set in AVD settings: accelerometer to off and magnetic field to off. Now it works.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with SDK r16 (Dec 2011), turning off accelerometer and magnetic field did not help.

So finally I recreated AVD and turned off 3 things in avd properties: Accelerometer, Magnetic field and Orientation. Now it works good.